# Twitter timeline iteration to get all of my tweets with a for loop

Tags: python, twitter, iteration, timeline

With this script i'm trying to iterate through my timeline with the twitter api. 
I'm using time delay in a "for" loop to get all of my tweets in  a List of objects like this:

```
x = [<twitter.status.Status at 0x7fb23b7c5090>, <twitter.status.Status at 0x7fb5fdb7c5090>,<twitter.status.Status at 0x7fbs4b7c5090>,<twitter.status.Status at 0x7f255b7c5090>, ...]

#Setting the connection:
api = twitter.Api(consumer_key= cons_key,
                  consumer_secret = cons_secret,
                  access_token_key = accs_token,
                  access_token_secret = accs_token_secret)

#Getting the latest id and put it on a list called "lis"

x = api.GetUserTimeline(screen_name = "My_Username", count = 1, include_rts = True)
lis=[x[0].id]

#Creating a list to append my twitter status objects.
tweet_info = []

## Iterate through all tweets, say for example 4 times
for i in range(0, 4): 
## tweet extract method with the last list item as the max_id

    user_timeline = api.GetUserTimeline(screen_name="My_Username",
    count=3, include_rts = True, max_id=lis[-1])

    time.sleep(2) ## 2 seconds rest between api calls

    for tweet in range(len(user_timeline)):
    x = user_timeline[tweet]
        tweet_info.append(x)
        lis.append(tweet['id']) #appending the id's in order to my list in order to extract the last one for the next time it iterates.
```

### When i run my code i'm getting this error:

```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-103-11f235fc3b3a> in <module>()
      7         x = user_timeline[tweet]
      8         tweet_info.append(x)
----> 9         lis.append(tweet['id'])

TypeError: 'int' object has no attribute '__getitem__'
```

What am I doing wrong and how can be fixed?

Comment: if i use the print command then i doesn't give me the object formation (<twitter.status.Status at 0x7fb23b7c5090>) but i show the hole object inside. 
And the it crashes with the TypeError: 'int' object has no attribute '__getitem__'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is because tweet is an `integer`

**Your code:**

```
for tweet in range(len(user_timeline)):
    x = user_timeline[tweet]
    tweet_info.append(x)
    lis.append(tweet['id'])
```

**You are internally doing this:**

```
1["id"]
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: 'int' object has no attribute '__getitem__'
```

That is :

```
 for i in range(len(a)):
    print i
    print i["id"]

 1
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: 'int' object has no attribute '__getitem__'
```

Comment: So the write way to do this would be ???

lis.append(user_timeline[tweet['id']] ?

Comment: @GiorgosPerakis tweet is just an `int` try printing tweet before x you will get an idea

Comment: @GiorgosPerakis could you print user_timeline and and it's type

Comment: i did that and it's a number. I understand that.  But how can i write that final piece of code ? :/

Comment: user_timeline[tweet]  #for tweet = 0 

<twitter.status.Status at 0x7fb55b7b38d0>

Comment: @GiorgosPerakis what it has

Comment: @GiorgosPerakis print it

Comment: @GiorgosPerakis try `x["id"]` what do you get

Comment: I found it! It works like a charm :)

 for tweet in range(len(user_timeline)):
        x = user_timeline[tweet]
        tweet_info.append(x)
        lis.append(user_timeline[tweet].id)

Comment: @GiorgosPerakis `x["id"]` will also do the same thing

Comment: I"ll try it. Thanks again for your help !